# Batch processing individual frames into video

Tags: video, editing

I’m new at video editing… and hoping someone can direct me to the best software for my needs.

Running on windows OS. I need to build a video from frames in tga format, convert them in different formats like .mov or .avi and sometimes with different compressions types (none, animation, jpeg).

I also need to be able to set the frame rate and add an audio track.

The software I’m looking for should be able to batch process the jobs as I have many frames in different scenes/folders.

From the reading I’ve been doing I would say virtualdub is the way to go but would like to know what other alternatives are out there.

Hoping I can gain I little more insight here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some options:

- **VirtualDub** can join still images to videos. Just select the first
  image, choose a compression, and save the video. That's some mouse
  clicks per folder, but no automatic batch procession.
- **FFmpeg** can do the same, but you need to write a command line for
  each folder, which can then be automatically batch processed.

Answer (score 3):

As for FFmpeg see [How do I encode single pictures into movies?](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f) Additional info:

- Use a recent ffmpeg build. Development is very active and [online
  documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) corresponds to recent FFmpeg code. Windows users
  can acquire it from [Zeranoe FFmpeg builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).
- Declare your frame rate (`-framerate` option) as an input option. The output
  will then use this same frame rate, or you can declare both an input
  and output frame rate with `-r`; for example if you need to read the input
  frames at a certain fps and need a standard output rate. Note that
  frames will simply be dropped or duplicated for non-matching input
  and output frame rates. Default is `-framerate 25` if you do omit this option.
- Additional streams (audio, video, subtitle, etc) are easy to add, and a complete command may look like:

  ```
  ffmpeg -framerate 24 -pattern_type glob -i 'frames*.png' -i audio.aac -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -preset slower -crf 23 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
  ```
- See [Using ffmpeg with decimal wildcard](https://superuser.com/a/523164/110524) for additional image to video examples, and [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) and [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) to get a good quality output.

Comment: Probably good to use much higher than default quality for temp files you're going to feed to a NLE before making a final encode to publish.

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point, but I didn't see a reference to a NLE in the question, but if that's what the file is going to be used in then I recommend a compressed lossless format such as [UT Video](http://umezawa.dyndns.info/archive/utvideo/?C=M;O=D). `ffmpeg` can natively decode and encode it, and Premiere can after UT Video is installed.

Comment: How's support for lossless h.264 in the non-ffmpeg world of commercial software?  I'm working on a question+answer about good lossless formats for this job, with some benchmark tests.  So far lossless x264 and utvideo are the two good choices, as I suggested in my answer to this question.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not sure about the current situation. I haven't tested it in a NLE for ages and will be unable to do so for at least 10 days because of travel.

Answer (score 2):

In the special case of jpeg input, you can do it losslessly by just muxing the data into an MJPEG stream, saving huge amounts of CPU time.

[How to losslessly encode a jpg image sequence to a video in ffmpeg?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7903/ffmpeg-how-to-losslessly-encode-many-jpg-images-to-a-video/14575#14575)

You're probably doing some kind of video editting on the results, so don't skimp on the quality of the files you make.  Prob. best to use lossless x264 (`ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264rgb -preset ultrafast -qp 0`), or utvideo, for your non-jpeg inputs.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon Fred42vid's answer (I won't go into VirtualDub since 1. I don't know it and 2. it's a GUI tool, and so should be relatively easy to use): if the images are named image001.jpg, image002.jpg, etc, you can use ffmpeg like so:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 16 -i image%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

Control the number of images per second by changing `-r 16`: as it is, that will give you 16 images per second (film uses 24 fps, PAL video uses 25, NTSC uses 29.97).

`%03d`means that ffmpeg will look for incremental images, starting at 001 and going up to 999. `%02d` would get you 01-99.

If you don't have the files named in this way, you can use the following:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -r 16 -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

This will input the jpg files in alphanumeric order.

For information about encoding the video with x264, [see this guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide).